# Div flickers when mouse hovers over it

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a mouseout and a mouseover event which change the div's opacity.

But the div flickers if the you move the mouse over and out of the div in rapid succession.

I'm trying to find a way to stop the flickering so that it cancels the previous action and thus won't flicker.
I used a clear interval but doesn't seem to fix the problem... this is my fiddle:

***http://jsfiddle.net/3xuyc/4/***

My code code which clears interval for opacity transition:

```
function fade(dir){
 var interId = null;
    function fade_in() {
        clearInterval(interId);
        var div_id = document.getElementById('my_div');
        var opacity = window.getComputedStyle(div_id).opacity;
        interId = transition_opacity(div_id, opacity, 1, 0);
    }
   function fade_out() {
        clearInterval(interId);
        var div_id = document.getElementById('my_div');
        var opacity = window.getComputedStyle(div_id).opacity;
        interId = transition_opacity(div_id, opacity, 0,0);
   }

    if(dir){      
        fade_in();
    } else {
        fade_out();
    }
}

var div_id = document.getElementById('my_div');
    div_id.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){fade(1);}, false);
    div_id.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){fade(0);}, false);
```

Any suggestions on how i can fix this problem?

Comment: Two things might be going on here. 1 - the flicker occurs when you mouse in and then out and then in because it's trying to perform both a fade in and fade out simultaneously so the opacity is constantly being conflicted. 2 - incrementing by 0.1 might cause a slight flicker, perhaps go with something finer like 0.05.

Comment: Yes but i have a clearInterval to prevent that or at least thats the idea.

Comment: Have you considered using the `div:hover` CSS sudo element to achieve the same effect with CSS? It'd be much easier and faster than using JavaScript. -- http://jsfiddle.net/3xuyc/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using `clearInterval` to stop the previous fade in/out.

Try declaring `var inter_id` outside the `fade()` function. You're setting it to `null` each time you call `fade()`.

Comment: Ah of course! So obvious now that you pointed it out! Thank you !